# Can't create a SSL certificate. [bash:server.key:Permission Denied]

Tags: fedora, permissions, io-redirection, openssl

i'm a student and i'm trying to make a SSL certificate because i'm following this guide:
https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=Fedora_27&p=httpd&f=13

**I'm running in vbox Fedora Server 38**

I got this output:

```
[wlima@wlimaserver certs]$ sudo umask 77 ; /usr/bin/openssl genrsa -aes128 2048 > server.key
[sudo] password for wlima:
bash: server.key: Permission denied
```

I already checked the audit.log to search for something related with the openssl. [sudo grep "openssl" /var/log/audit/audit.log] , nothing displayed.
I have the 731 value in this directory, so i think that it isn't a permissions related problem.
I even runned the mount command to make sure that i didn't have this mounted as read-only.

```
[wlima@wlimaserver certs] mount 
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime) 
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel) 
devtmpfs on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,seclabel,size=4096k,nr_inodes=494111,mode=755,inode64) 
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime) 
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,seclabel,inode64) 
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,seclabel,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000) 
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,seclabel,size=799124k,nr_inodes=819200,mode=755,inode64) 
cgroup2 on /sys/fs/cgroup type cgroup2 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel,nsdelegate,memory_recursiveprot) 
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel) 
bpf on /sys/fs/bpf type bpf (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,mode=700) 
ramfs on /run/credentials/systemd-vconsole-setup.service type ramfs (ro,nosuid,nodey,noexec,relatime,seclabel,mode=700) 
configfs on /sys/kernel/config type configfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime) 
dev/mapper/fedora-root on / type xfs (rw,relatime,seclabel,attr2,inode64,logbufs=8,logbsize=32k,noquota) 
selinuxfs on /sys/fs/selinux type selinuxfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime) 
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=33,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=20733) 
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime,seclabel,pagesize=2M) 
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mgueue (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel) 
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel) 
tracefs on /sys/kernel/tracing type tracefs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel) 
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime) 
ramfs on /run/credentials/systemd-sysctl.service type ramfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel,mode=700) 
ramfs on /run/credentials/systemd-sysusers.service type ramfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel,mode=700) 
ramfs on /run/credentials/systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service type ramfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel,mode=700) 
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,seclabel,size=1997812k,nr_inodes=1048576,inode64) 
dev/sda2 on /boot type xfs (rw,relatime,seclabel,attr2,inode64,1ogbufs=8,logbsize=32k,noquota) 
ramfs on /run/credentials/systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service type ramfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel,mode=700) 
ramfs on /run/credentials/systemd-resolved.service type ramfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel,mode=700) 
sunrpc on /yar/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs type rpc_pipefs (rw,relatime) 
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,seclabel,size=399560k,nr_inodes=99890,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000,inode64) [wima@wlimaserver certs]$
```

I will be thankfull if someone would be able to help me!

**EDIT:**

I modified the command for this:

```
sudo umask 77 ; sudo /usr/bin/openssl genrsa -aes128 2048 > server.key
```

It still gives me the same Permission denied output

Comment: probably you will need to add sudo before the openssl command as it doesn't pass for the first command to the second one.

Comment: Your 2nd command (sudo chmod...; sudo ...) need privileges too.

Comment: please refrain from pasting your input/output as screenshots - they are hard to read, cannot be copied nor searched. Kindly copy and format using the proper tools of U&L. see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help)

Comment: @admstg @K-att-
I modified the command for this:
`sudo umask 77 ; sudo /usr/bin/openssl genrsa -aes128 2048 > server.key`
It still gives me the same Permission denied output

Comment: @FelixJN I'm sorry, i will modify next time! Thanks for tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR

Use `sudo -i` to become `root`. You may also ommit `sudo` in front of commands now.

Long story

The redirection does not take `sudo` as you would expect. You would need `tee` or something to work around the issue. You effectively try to write with `> server.key` which will never work in restricted directory.

Comment: Thanks alot for your help! It worked. One more thing that i learned today! I wanted to upvote but i don't have enough reputation to do it.

Comment: Apart from upvoting, if the answer helped you, we usually expect an Acceptation which is just under the up-down votes. Cheers, and I am glad it helped.

Comment: Thanks for telling me it, didn't know it! Already accepted!